# magento 2 get block by alias

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks

Can I retrieve a block instance using it's alias (`as="alias"`) within a template?

I'm aware this can be done for the block name, for example:

```
$block->getLayout()->getBlock('BLOCK_NAME');
```

I'm looking for a way to do this using the alias specifically:

```
$block->getLayout()->getBlockByAlias('BLOCK_ALIAS');
```

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2 you are able to load block also by alias in this way:

`echo $block->getChildHtml('BLOCK_ALIAS');`
or
`echo $this->getChildHtml('BLOCK_ALIAS');`

Some useful info (also about blocks and rendering):
https://blog.philwinkle.com/the-most-misunderstood-concept-in-magento/

Comment: Either provide short answer in comment or provide more information

Comment: the question relates to magento 2 rather than magento 1